# Visual Studio does not react after EF "Enable-Migration"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to switch from Automatic Migrations to regular Migrations in EF 6 with Visual Studio 2017 [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211196/how-to-switch-from-ef-automatic-migrations-to-regular-migrations).

After typing `Enable-Migrations` including a connection string and a dbcontext in the Package Manager Console, Visual Studio does not react anymore. I have been waiting 30 minutes. The respective database contains about 100 filled tables (but seems to be untouched from what I can see in SQL studio). I have tried the command twice with different contexts and the same outcome. Is Visual Studio actually still working in the background (CPU usage 0.4%)? Any suggestions on fixing this?

Comment: Looking at this and your previous question, looks like you misunderstand the meaning of the "automatic" and "regular" migration. The important is that both are **migrations**, so you should already have them enabled, so there is no need of `Enable-Migrations` command.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh wow, I thought I had to overwrite the existing migration because that was configured to be automatic. I will try to manually add migrations now and come back to you if that works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the main question:

If Visual Studio does not react after the `Enable-Migration` command, from my experience you are doing something wrong. In my case, migrations have already been enabled before and there was already a generic "Migrations" folder. Furthermore, I mixed multiple dbContexts in this folder which is impossible and leads to weird error messages (and maybe even to Visual Studio not responding anymore).

More specifically for my issue with multiple contexts:

If you have multiple dbContexts in the database, it turns out that using migrations gets a bit more complex. Basically, you need to enable migrations for each context and specify a unique MigrationsDirectory. [Details on this topic can be found here](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/entityframework/entity-framework-6-code-first-migrations-with-multiple-data-contexts). Deleting the Migrations folder in my project and applying the following commands for each dbContext separately, solved the issue for me:

```
enable-migrations -ContextTypeName MultiDataContextMigrations.Models.DataContext -MigrationsDirectory:DataContextMigrations
Add-Migration -configuration MultiDataContextMigrations.DataContextMigrations.Configuration Initial
Update-Database -configuration MultiDataContextMigrations.DataContextMigrations.Configuration -Verbose
```